# web design business: use my personal name or create a business name. which will attract more customers?

Tags: business-models

I am about to set up a website to sell my skills. I already own a domain in my name e.g. `www.firstnamelastname.com` but I see other businesses around my area using a made up title e.g. something like `www.midlanddesigns.com`. I'm wondering if it make a difference? Would setting it up under a personal name make it more personal to customers? Or would a made up title look more attractive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in the end there isn't a huge difference. Here are the things I have considered in the process myself:

1. Are you selling a specific product(s) with your company? If you are using your name, it won't differentiate your company from others.
2. Do you plan to grow the company to a large non-regional size?  Again using your name can be a detriment in those cases.
3. Do you plan on selling consulting/contract services associated to you or eventually a small team of people that report to you?  If you do using your name has a lot of value as you essentially become a local brand.
4. Do you ever plan on selling the company?  Using your name may make people less willing to buy it as you are essentially a piece of the company and owning the company without you would probably require a name change.

One thing to consider as well, do you ever think you will have family members working at your company?  I have seen a lot of marketing firms just use their initials and their last name.  For example J Doe Design or CR Smith Web Development.  This solves a number of issues because you name is on the company but it isn't 100% tied to you.

It gives you more room if you hire relatives or children because if you are John Doe and your daughter is Jane Doe,then J Doe covers you both.  Even if the family member doesn't have the same initials people won't often question it under the assumption the other family member is using a nickname.

It also gives you the ability to sell the company and the name won't matter.  Someone off the street won't know that you are the J Doe that used to own J Doe Web Development.

Adding in the Web Development, Development, Design, etc gives some clue as to what your company does so it isn't confused with a J Doe Insurance company that opens in the future.

If you look around at companies big and small most of the ones you that use a persons first and last name are built of the brand of the person because that person is a celebrity at some level.

Finally, don't get analysis paralysis about the name.  If you decide in the future you don't like it your want to create a specific product you can always create another company or create a DBA (doing business as) to cover the change you want.  Many companies use DBAs all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I personally did a business name, not only because then I could theme my advertising, but also because it removes confusion when I hire subject matter experts to help.  If you're running as a one man show, sometimes people expect you not to sub work.

Bonus if you have a catchy name people will remember.

Comment: That's why I'm glad my parents named me Steve Shittlemeyer